# How to get current Login Facebook Messenger ID from laravel?

Tags: laravel, chatbot, messenger

I want to know current login messenger user id from laravel. It is possible?
Because I need to check current messenger id is valid to open web url. Now I am using laravel + botman.

Answer (score 0):

After login success, store the values of Facebook in users table where the user_id resides , and when it needed, just get it from db using Auth::user()->messengerid .

Or follow the documents [Get Facebook id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/)

Comment: actually I am not ok yet.

Comment: @MyatHtut What is the issue ? Could you please explain it?

Comment: Actually I would like to handle web view. I would like to check messenger_id from my database and current login messenger_id.